# meteor can't access cross origin

Tags: meteor, cross-domain

i got a problem in meteor when i try to make a cross origin call.
when i make the call using Ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: signoutUrl,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (nullResponse) {
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log('error in HTTP ::  >>>>' + JSON.stringify(e));
               }
        });
```

it works fine with no problem. but when i am using meteor's HTTP.call method for the same Http request it sent me the error.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

i set the parameters and header in meteor **Http.call** are

```
HTTP.call(method, URL, 
 {params: {
 async: false,
 contentType: "application/json",
 dataType: 'jsonp'},
 headers:{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'https://www.google.com/*'}
 }, function (err, result) {}
```

but when i check the request. i found the header is like

> access-control-request-headers:access-control-allow-origin

so, help me where i am wrong in this HTTP request and how to resolve it

Comment: If you use HTTP.call server side it will work. I don't how to answer your question though because according to the docs, it should also work client side with the right headers.

Comment: i also try to call from sever side and it work fine but i am working on Google log-out and it will not make log-out when the request is done form the server.

Comment: You know about the accounts-google package right? That does google login and logout

Comment: ya i know about that package but i want Google log-in on my custom page and button

Comment: You should still be using accounts-google for custom ui. Check out the useraccounts packages. They help you customise the login experience